# AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object attribute 'execute' is read-only

Tags: python, sqlite, python-decorators

I attempted to manually decorate `sqlite3.Connection.execute` but wasn't allowed to. Is there a way around this other than decorating the `sqlite3.Connection` object itself directly?

My code:

```
    db = g._db = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DB_PATH'])

    def allow_direct_commit(f_execute):
        @functools.wraps(f_execute)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            r = f_execute(*args, **kwargs)
            r.commit = db.commit
            return r

        return decorated

    db.execute = allow_direct_commit(db.execute)
```

My goal was to be able to do:

```
 db.execute('whatever').commit()
```

if I wanted to instead of:

```
db.execute('whatever')
db.commit()
```

**Note:** I'm using Flask, not that it should matter for this example.

**EDIT:** It turns out that decorating `sqlite3.Connection` itself was trickier and nastier than I thought. I also had to use similar hack to set `commit` to the `sqlite3.Cursor` and also had to add the `__iter__` method manually. I'm not sure why. I thought `__getattribute__` would have taken take of that but instead I got a `TypeError: 'Cursor' object is not iterable`. Finally, sadly, you can't `functools.wraps` a class.

If anyone can come up with a better version, I'd be happy to see it.

```
    db  = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DB_PATH'])

    def allow_direct_commit(db):
        db_execute = db.execute

        @functools.wraps(db_execute)
        def decorated_execute(*args, **kwargs):
            r = db_execute(*args, **kwargs)

            class Cursor:
                def __getattribute__(self, attr):
                    if attr == 'commit':
                        return db.commit

                    return getattr(r, attr)

                def __iter__(self):
                    return r.__iter__()

            return Cursor()

        class DB:
            def __getattribute__(self, attr):
                if attr == 'execute':
                    return decorated_execute

                return getattr(db, attr)

        return DB()

    db = allow_direct_commit(db)

    g._db = db
```

Comment: Maybe accessing the attributes directly? Wherever they are stored (maybe in `__dicts__` or something). I will check the code source if I have the time (or someone else can).